# Javascript implementation of interval search tree

Tags: javascript, data-structures

Is there a [boost ICL](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/libs/icl/doc/html/index.html) equivalent interval search tree in javascript? I am new to javascript. What's the best way to find optimised data structure implementations for javascript?

Application: The requirement is to get US based zip-codes as input and return the name of state (as string) containing the zip-code as output. 
Eg: input: 95630, output: "CA"
I thought an interval search tree would be a nice way to search for state quickly. I can store the zipcode range as the range of the interval in each node and the value as a string containing the state name in string in the node.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don’t know what boost icl is but there are a few interval trees for js. Here is one.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-interval-tree

I think there is at least one zip code with two states, and I’m not sure it’s at a border case.  I haven’t done zip codes in a long time but this zip code (somewhere on the east coast) caused issues for most of the devs.